# Is it possible to update jquery tab set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery tab set:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Mileage Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Trips</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">something</div>
  <div-id="tabs-2">something</div>
</div>
```

My content on my tabs fires some javascript code that posts form data (I included that code). The problem is that I would like the tab element to refresh so any new content can be shown. Is there a built-in way to refresh the tabs using the "success:" option. I am currently using "location.reload();" but it just refreshes the whole page. Not ideal.

Thanks.

**My Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      //Submit form to add record.
      $('#addmileage').submit(function (e) 
      {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        data: $('#addmileage').serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        url:'actionpages/add_trip.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>',
        success: function(){
        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
         location.reload();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            }
        });
    });



      $('.deleteMileageForm').submit(function (e) 
      {          

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), // **** modified this line ****
        type:'POST',
        url:'actionpages/delete_trip.cfm',
        success: function () {
            $('.successTab2').fadeIn(200).show();
            location.reload();
            $('.errorTab2', $row).fadeOut(200).hide();
            }

        });
    });


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I think you could achieve this, is to have the server-side functions you're calling in AJAX, return a block of HTML which you could inject into the  of the tab you want to reload.  And if you're going to do that, you'll need to put the functions in a CFC instead of the CFM page you're calling now.

So, you would generate the way you're doing now to build the initial page, but save the generated HTML as a string and then return it to the jQuery AJAX call.

As just a really bare-bones example:

```
$('.deleteMileageForm').submit(function (e) 
  {          

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(), // **** modified this line ****
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url:'actionpages/actions.cfc?method=deleteTrip&returnformat=json',
    success: function (result) {
        $('.successTab2').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('.errorTab2', $row).fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('#tab2').html(result);
        }

    });
```

Then on the server you'll need an **actions.cfc** with remotely accessible functions:

```
<component>
    <cffunction name="deleteTrip" access="remote">
        <cfset newHTML = "<h1>This is new HTML!</h1>">
        <cfreturn newHTML>
    </cffunction>
</component>
```

I've put everything into JSON format, just because I always use JSON. :)

Not sure how familiar you are with CFCs, returnformats, etc.  But hopefully this is a push in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, so the newHTML variable could be a success message or something that I send back into my tab right.? And the cfc would also need my query as well correct?

Comment: Yep, you can send back whatever you need.  If you just need a status message you can send that, or your could rebuild and send the entire content of the tab if you like.  Totally flexible.  And yes, you would put your delete query into the deleteTrip function of the cfc so that it executes before anything is returned to your page.

Comment: Got it. So I am able to get it working using your samples. Thanks. If I return html text to the tabs id, the whole tab set is replaced with my text. Not ideal. The only other thing I could get working is return the html text to the active tab. But that just adds the text, doesn't refresh the tabs after it adds it. What do you me an by rebuilding the content of the tab?

Comment: Well, you just nned to make sure you're only replacing the content of the element you want to update.  So if you only want to update a status message within tab2, perhaps add into your page <span id="tab2Message"></span>.  Then when you can use $('#tab2Message').html(result);

Comment: Adding the original code that shows my tab to my success code reloads the entire tab element:       $('#include-from-outside').load('trip_tab.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>'); . Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the tabs in the success function using [DOM Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). It may be the case, that your scripts like `actionpages/delete_trip.cfm` have to return new information which you need to refresh the tabs (for example in the [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format).

Some notes:

- The function `location.reload();` may reload the page from the browser cache. Use `location.reload(true);` if you do not want this behavior.
- `$('.successTab2').fadeIn(200)` should be enough (`.show()` is not needed). You also do not need the `.hide()` function.

Comment: Ok, so if I have my actionpages return some Json data, which Method should I be using to refresh?

Comment: You can only refresh the whole site. There is no refresh for single tags. But can update their CSS, Content, attributes, ... via JavaScript (for example with jQuery). Have a look on the site http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ how you can manipulate the HTML tags with jQuery.

Comment: How about this: I'm showing the content that has tabs by using $('#include-from-outside').load('trip_tab.cfm?ticketid=<cfoutput>#url.ticketid#</cfoutput>'); . Is there a way I could have that fire again once the success function happens?

Comment: You can do this but it may not be an elegant solution (You also have to specify ``data`` as a second argument). I recommend you to have a look at the demos of the various function. In the end you will have a good idea, how you can update the DOM via jQuery.